# Error creating bean with name 'ModelAccess' Injection of autowired dependencies failed; Could not autowire field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is structure of my project :

scr/main/java/com/company/configuration

scr/main/java/com/company/controller

scr/main/java/com/company/myProject

scr/main/java/com/company/exception

In configuration I have 3 classes : ProjectInitializer, ProjectConfiguration and ProjectContextListener.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company"})
 @EnableJpaRepositories("com.company")
public class ProjectConfiguration {

}
```

========================================================================

```
public class ProjectInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ProjectConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new ProjectContextListener());

    }
}
```

====================================================================

public class ProjectContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    Security.addProvider(new FlexiCoreProvider());
    Security.addProvider(new FlexiECProvider());
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    System.out.println("Shutting down!");
}
```

}

======================================================================

I want to make connection to oracle database in myproject package. it consists some classes, the problem is with ModelAccess class:

```
@Service
public class ModelAccess {
    @Autowired
    ProjectRepository jpaRepository;
    protected JpaRepository<ProjectEnt, Long> getJpaRepository() {
        return jpaRepository;
    }
}
```

============================================================================

```
@Transactional
public interface ProjectRepository extends
        JpaRepository<ProfileEnt, Long>,IProjectRepository{


}
```

============================================================================

```
@Repository
public interface IProjectRepository extends IGenericRepository<ProfileEnt> {
}
```

=================================================================

This is stack trace when I deploy my project in tomcat:

Error creating bean with name 'ModelAccess': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
com.company.myproject.impl.ProjectRepository com.company.myProject.impl.ModelAccess.jpaRepository;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [com.company.myproject.impl.ProjectRepository] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

============================================================================
This is part of my pom file:

```
 <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.11.RELEASE</version>
            <!--<version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: As separate issues: Use Spring Boot's embedded container if at all possible, you're using substantially outdated dependencies, use of `I*` for interfaces in Java is discouraged, and why are you injecting this `ModelAccess` just to provide a handle to the repository instead of injecting the repository?

Comment: (To your immediate issue, it looks like you probably don't have `@EnableJpaRepositories` or equivalent anywhere.)

Comment: I cannot use spring boot to my project. It is an old project that i cannot change structure and i should add something to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that `IProjectRepository` is not a `JpaRepository`. And moreover, looks like you don't need it. To fix it just remove `IProjectRepository` and use `ProjectRepository` instead.

Comment: I have added @repository to IprojectRepository. How do you say it is not jpa repository?

Comment: @Repository annotation doesn't make this class a repo, it is the same as @Component. To have a Repository you should extend from JpaRepository (as you did for `ProjectRepository`).

Comment: Here the problem is it cannot autowire. Even if IprojectRepository is not a jpaRepository it is a bean. Why it can autowire it?